# Average color of an image behind a given DIV,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know is it possible or not but I have tried a lot and could not find anything. I want to get the average of the image color behind the text. I find all solutions finding an average color of the whole image. I don't want this. I have a text box in a div for example and I only need the average color of the image covering the text only not whole average color of the image. For example this is the image

[image]

My first textbox is textbox1 and I only want the average color of just the div part of the image(sky average color in case of textbox1) and textbox2 (road average color).

Comment: So find the element position relative to the image and get the coordinates. Change the image processing average code to use that area.

Comment: @epascarello i found this http://jsfiddle.net/xLF38/818/ but where can i set the coordinates for example div is div {
   left:50px;
    top:100px;
    width: 120px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    margin: 0;
}

Comment: If this is so that you can find out the text color that keeps the best contrast with a busy background image, rather than calculating the background color, you may want to try adding a text-shadow that contrasts with the text color.

Comment: @LieRyan how can i do that thats the problem

Comment: @user3754676: that's not the problem, that's your attempt at a solution. For best result, you should ask on SO about your problem, not your solution. Why do you want to know the background image's color? If this is so you can provide sufficient contrast on the text, then you can use a hard text-shadow. If you have light text and dark shadow, the shadow will be invisible in dark background but the light text gives contrasts, in light background the text shadow instead provides contrast.

Comment: I sense this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: well thanks for your time i am already working on the solution given by Cinn. Thanks again Lie Ryan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70019/discussion-between-user3754676-and-lie-ryan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT : i answered a full example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271324/average-color-of-an-image-of-selected-region-giving-wrong-image/28280541#answer-28280541).

---

Using canvas you can retrieve all the image data:

```
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="500" height="500"> 
  // alternative text
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var c = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  var image = new Image(); 
  image.src = 'image.jpg';
  image.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(this,0,0);
  }

  function average_color(left, top, width, height) { // these parameters correspond to the coordinates of your box
      var imageData = ctx.getImageData(left, top, width, height);
      var mapPixel = imageData.data;

      var red = 0,
          green = 0,
          blue = 0,
          nb_pixels = width * height;
      for(var i=0;i<nb_pixels;i+=4) {
          red += mapPixel[i];
          green += mapPixel[i+1];
          blue += mapPixel[i+2];
          // mapPixel[i+3] is the component of transparency, I do not think it will be useful to you. Useless with jpg that does not support transparency.
    }
    nb_pixels = nb_pixels / 4;
    red = Math.round(red/nb_pixels);
    green = Math.round(green/nb_pixels);
    blue = Math.round(blue/nb_pixels);
    return [red,green,blue]; // components of the average color
  }
</script>
```

More informations about pixel manipulation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas).
If you do not want your image to be in a canvas all the time, you can generate the canvas tag the time of the calculation with javascript and delete it after ...

The problem with this method is that canvas is [not supported by all browsers](http://guides.instructure.com/s/2204/m/4214/l/41056-which-browsers-does-canvas-support?). This can also cause performance problems. Cache the results of calculations if possible.

Comment: yes thats the problem i can not use canvas http://caniuse.com/#search=html5%20canvas)

Comment: Perhaps you can do these calculations on server side and send the results via ajax? (storing the results to only make once) ?

Comment: this should be the client side project no server side interactions :/

Comment: there are some errors in the caniuse, canvas is supported by firefox from gecko 1.8 (firefox 1.5), and Internet Explorer from version 10. And apparently [reading pixels is managed from Internet Explorer 9](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974957(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: i have tried this but it is not working and getting an error (SecurityError: The operation is insecure)  Am i doing anything wrong?Can you make a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Sorry maybe I will do it tonight I have to work now. I would say it has to go through a real server or a local server (with [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/) for example). [Some informations here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#security-with-canvas-elements).

Comment: yes i am using wamp thanks and can you see this i have updated the question and not working when i am changing the coordinates. Can you see this please thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271324/average-color-of-an-image-of-selected-region-giving-wrong-image @Cinn